# How to use a template type in a template method specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

I'm trying to create custom containers, and use those as return types in a template class.
I'm having to use C++98, so wonder how to get the following to compile:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

/// Make a container called Vector<T>
template<typename T>
struct Vector
{
  typedef std::vector<T> type;
}; 

/// Some ordinary class that holds that data.
class Data
{

public:
    Data();

    template<typename T>
    typename Vector<T>::type* getVec();

    /// Specialization
    template<>
    typename Vector<int>::type* getVec();
};
```

The error from the compiler is:
`error: no function template matches function template specialization 'getVec'`

Why does the 'int' specialization of getVec() not work?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should almost *never* use pointers to containers. What is the underlying problem you try to solve with a function like `getVec()`? Why does it need to return a pointer? And what is the problem you try to solve with the `Vector` structure template and its `type` member type alias?

Comment: I am trying to create an alias for something like, typedef map<string, MyRecord> Table<MyRecord> without all the mess that comes with trying to read containers that hold containers. i.e. MyRecord would also be a std::map<int, string>, but map<string, map<int, string>> doesn't read well...

Comment: Is there a problem with having a container on the heap? I'm trying to make some factory like methods, it's just going to copy a load of data into a handy container, but not be responsible for it.

Comment: Generally allocation on heap and doing your own manual and explicit dynamic memory handling is a rather big source of bugs, some which have lead to major security flaws in the past. Compilers are pretty good at *eliding* copying (and it's mandatory in some cases) so returning vectors by value will often be more effective anyway and safer anyway. And if the compiler can't elide copying in some situation, then perhaps it can move (or you could explicitly `std::move` it).

Comment: Also by using pointers you must dreference it each time you want to use the `[]` operator. By using objects and references (when possible) you'll save writing three special characters each time you want to access an element in the vector.

Answer (score 3):

The C++98 rules about the placement of specialisations are somewhat less intuitive than modern C++.

Suffice it to say, you need to place the specialisation at namespace scope

```
/// Specialization - declare after the class
template<>
Vector<int>::type* Data::getVec<int>();
```

Beyond that, you must specify the `<int>` parameter explicitly since it's not deducible in the function's declaration. I also removed the redundant `typename` (we are now in a context with concrete types).

Answer (score 1):

You might do

```
/// Some ordinary class that holds that data.
class Data
{

public:
    Data();

    template<typename T>
    typename Vector<T>::type* getVec();


};

/// Specialization
template<>
Vector<int>::type* Data::getVec<int>()
{
    return NULL;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/36qPcnPzG)